# Terraform for_each for nested value

Tags: terraform

The main idea is to create several env_var for one environment (production and development) in a GitHub repo.

Using these variables, I can pass through `each.key` Keys are the environment names.
However, I need to realize how I iterate over nested values.
What do I need to use instead `local.env_vars_git[each.key][0]["env_var_name"]`?

```
locals {
  env_vars_git = {
    production = [
      {
        env_var_name           = "hostname_01"
        env_var_value          = "%s"
      },
      {
        env_var_name           = "hostname_02"
        env_var_value          = "%s"
      }
    ],
    development = [
      {
        env_var_name           = "hostname_01"
        env_var_value          = "%s"
      },
      {
        env_var_name           = "hostname_02"
        env_var_value          = "%s"
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource "github_actions_environment_variable" "aws" {
  for_each      = local.env_vars_git
  repository    = github_repository.aws.name
  environment   = each.key
  variable_name = local.env_vars_git[each.key][0]["env_var_name"]
  value         = local.env_vars_git[each.key][0]["env_var_value"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: The first step is to transform your variable into a more optimal structure. Is that option available to you in this situation, or are you forced to work with the current structure?

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard - thank you. I'm looking for a better structure.
[This structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77073715/terraform-for-each-in-creating-github-enviroment-variables) works, but trying to create `environment` twice.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have done nested loops in terraform is using modules...

- Outside we loop over the outer elements (environments)
- Pass the inner elements list as a parameter
- Inside the module we loop over the inner elements (env variables)

Below is an example:

I'm simplifying your locals but once you get the concept you can recomplicate that later if you like.

```hcl
locals {
  env_vars_git = {
    production = {
      hostname_01 = "foo_prod"
      hostname_02 = "bar_prod"
    },
    development = {
      hostname_01 = "foo_dev"
      hostname_02 = "bar_dev"
    }
  }
}

module "test" {
  source = "./env_vars"

  for_each    = local.env_vars_git
  repository  = "github_repository.aws.name"
  environment = each.key
  variables   = each.value
}
```

then the module code is:

```hcl
variable "repository" {
  type = string
}

variable "environment" {
  type = string
}

variable "variables" {
  type = map(string)
}

resource "null_resource" "sh_test" {
  for_each = var.variables
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when        = create
    command     = "echo '${each.value}' "
    interpreter = ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  }
}
```

You can see that I'm using a `null_resource` to just to output the values, but the same can be done with any other resource

...and terraform apply looks like

```txt
Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"]: Creating...
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo 'foo_dev' "]
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"] (local-exec): foo_dev
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=7355436237029689557]

module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"]: Creating...
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo 'foo_prod' "]
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"] (local-exec): foo_prod
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_01"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=4455254562097512830]

module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"]: Creating...
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo 'bar_dev' "]
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"] (local-exec): bar_dev
module.test["development"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=2018334306873294541]

module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"]: Creating...
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo 'bar_prod' "]
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"] (local-exec): bar_prod
module.test["production"].null_resource.sh_test["hostname_02"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=5766017297644124093]
```

I also have the code here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/tree/master/TerraForm/module_loop